# Pyinstaller and PyCryptoDome, Incompatible? or Something?

Tags: python

I have errors in using this two, particularly ImportError,  I have python2.7 in WIndows, installed pyCryptoDOme through pip, but having these errors, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Support for PyCryptodome (`pycryptodome` package) will be introduced only in the next version of PyInstaller.

Right now, the only option is to take the hook from the development branch:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/develop/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-Crypto.py

and then run PyInstaller with the option `--additional-hooks-dir`, to tell him where the custom hook is.

If you are installing the `pycryptodomex` package, the right hook is:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/develop/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-Cryptodome.py